# tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq output projection

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, embedding, recurrent-neural-network

The official documentation for `tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq` has the following explanation for the output_projection argument:

`output_projection`: None or a pair (W, B) of output projection weights and biases; W has shape [output_size x num_decoder_symbols] and B has shape [num_decoder_symbols]; if provided and feed_previous=True, each fed previous output will first be multiplied by W and added B.

I don't understand why the B argument should have the size of `[num_decoder_symbols]`? Since the output is first multiplied by W and then the biases are added, Shouldn't it be `[output_size]`?

Comment: This may be because tensorflow vectors (in this case B) are usually row vectors so multiplication is done as (uW + B) where u and B are both row vectors.

Comment: Oh no! I just tried setting up the code for the ouput_projection, and it turns out, whatever output_size you give, the final dimension always turns out to be equal to the ouput_size of the num_proj argument of the lstm-cell. Which still doesn't answer the original doubt: (Why biases are num_decoder_symbol ?)

Answer (score 0):

Alright! So, I have found the answer to the question. 
The main source of confusion was in the dimensions 
`[output_size x num_decoder_symbols]` of the W matrix itself.

The `output_size` here doesn't refer to the **output_size** that you want, but is the output_size (same as the size of the hidden vector) of the LSTM cell. Thus the matrix multiplication `u x W` will result in a vector of size `num_decoder_symbols` that can be considered as the logits for the output symbols.